# Payment gateway integration for sending an amount

Tags: python, django

I need your suggestion to integrate a payment gateway in my app. The situation is -

1. Customer will create a booking.
2. Driver will accept the booking.
3. After successful delivery customer will pay online. The amount will go to app owner.
4. Automatically, after deducting the commission, rest of the amount will go from app owner to driver account

So, here, I am getting two types of payment process -

1. receiving payment
2. sending payment

I can implement option 1(receiving payment) part normally with payment gateway integration.

But, my problem is with option 2(sending payment). Can we do it with payment gateway? If yes then give me some ideas. what should i search for or may be some service name... Any help would be appreciated..

Thanks..

(Note-paypal/stripe does not support the currency I am looking for).

**Edit - At least suggest me that,- can we transfer money to a bank account automatically from an app using a payment gateway..

Comment: You can take a look at instamojo : https://pypi.org/project/drf-instamojo/

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. I have checked your link but unfortunately I have not found any detail to transfer money to an account there.